# Trying to add deploy user to AWS Linux AMI but I can't SSH in to it

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-web-services

I’ve created a user called ‘deploy’ on my remote server and I’ve tried adding my public id_rsa.pub key to its .ssh/authorized_keys file (which I created), but I can’t connect to it. When I try to ssh into it I get "Permission denied (publickey)."

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Placing my rsd_id.pub key into the 'deploy' user's .ssh/authorized_keys file using:

   sudo su - deploy

   echo "long string key here" >> .ssh/authorized_keys

Then I cat .ssh/authorized_keys to confirm it's really there, which it is.

Then sshing by doing

```
ssh deploy@ec2-8380398230802.hostnamestuff.amazon.aws.com 'hostname; uptime'
```

I get the same Permission denied (publickey) with that.

2. I placed the rsa_id.pub key inside aws's keypairs. Same error.

What might be the issue here?

Comment: Are you sure that the ssh client is using the correct private key? Try specifying it exlicitly using the `-i` switch, e.g.: `ssh -i ~/.ssh/my_private_key ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer was to change the permissions for my .ssh and .ssh/authorized_keys director and file to 700 and 600 respectively. I thought I'd done this already but it now works. Who'd have known!?